# Automatically push ng-model data to array from view

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular-meteor

I'm populating my view as follow :

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="user in users">
    <tr>
      <td class="numeric">{{user.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I'm trying to access the data from `user.name` inside my controller so that I end up with an array of without any action from the user:

`$scope.array = [user.name1,user.name2,user.name3,...]`

I've been trying to do something like this but it's not working:

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="user in users">
    <tr>
      <td class="numeric" ng-model={{array[user.index] = user.name}}>{{user.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I need to get the data this way because i'm using data from `minimongo` on the client and can't access it before the page is loaded.

edit controller :

```
angular.module('App').controller('Users', function ($scope,$stateParams) {
  $scope.helpers({
    Users: () => {
      return Users.find({_id:$stateParams.ID.toString()});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems funny to me, you already have `users` array in your controller. From that array you can retrieve any value you need. Why you need to do that?

Comment: because i don't have the data in my controller, it's a mongodb cursor as an helper `
    users: () => {
      return Users.find({_id:$stateParams.ID.toString()});
    }`  but yes it's quite strange

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Comment: You have just added part of your code: `users: () => { return Users.find({_id:$stateParams.ID.toString()}); }`. Can you add detail code please?

Comment: added the whole controller

Comment: Also add `helpers()` method.

Comment: oh sorry http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.2/helpers

Comment: From this code: `$scope.helpers({
    Users: () => {
      return Users.find({_id:$stateParams.ID.toString()});
    }
  });`, it is possible to get the `users` array. Just try man, You will get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108608/discussion-between-user697-and-khalid-hussain).